# Infinity loop. Reading data from database and comparing them to with an if statment

Tags: android, database, sqlite, loops

My English is a little rusty, but I will try to explain what I want to do.

I have a database and 5 rows in it. 
I am trying to do something like this:

1. Read n rows from database.
2. Assign data from database to variables
3. Check if variables belongs to the condition
   `if(((szerokosc<=a)&&(szerokosc>=b)) && ((dlugosc>=c)&&(dlugosc<=d)))`
4. if yes, display (opis)
5. if not, display(brak danych)
6. if end of rows go to first
7. if there exists next row, go to it,

I want to do this over and over again;

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    showLocation(location);
    showAdditionalInfo(location);
    if(savedLocation == null)
    savedLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    DataBaseHelper zb = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    double szerokosc = location.getLatitude();
    double dlugosc = location.getLongitude();
    Cursor k = zb.dajCos();
    String lokalizacja = "Jestes na: ";
    while(k.moveToNext())
    {
        nazwa = k.getString(0);
        szmax= k.getDouble(1);
        szmin= k.getDouble(2);
        dlmin= k.getDouble(3);
        dlmax= k.getDouble(4);
        opis = k.getString(5);
        a=szmax;
        b=szmin;
        c=dlmin;
        d=dlmax; 
        if(k.moveToNext()==false){k.moveToFirst();}
    }
    if(((szerokosc&lt;=a)&&(szerokosc&gt;=b)) && ((dlugosc&gt;=c)&&(dlugosc&lt;=d)))
    {
        lokalizacja =nazwa+opis;
    }
    else
    {
        lokalizacja ="brak danych";
    }
    tvLokalizacja.setText(lokalizacja);
}
```

This is public Cursor `dajCos()`

```
public Cursor dajCos() 
{
     String[] kolumny={"nazwa","szmax","szmin","dlmin","dlmax","opis"};
     SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor kursor = db.query("obiekty", kolumny, null, null, null, null, null);
     return kursor;
}
```

I dont know how to explain this better. I will try to describe this in that way.

In database I have 5 records each of them include coordinates.
For example: My position corresponds to coordinates from second row , I want to display you are in "zone1", I move ten meters away and my position don't match to coordinates in any row so I want to  display "no data",  I move  fifteen meters away then fourth row coordinates match to my position and display you are in "zone2".

I hope  you will understand what I mean and help me.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to read database form begin to the end, check out whit statement
<code>
    if(((szerokosc<=a)&&(szerokosc>=b)) && ((dlugosc>=c)&&   (dlugosc<=d)))

</code>
and do this in infinity loop

Comment: Do you mean you want to do that in SQL? do you mean you want to do it with an SQL loop/cursor? Or do you mean you want an SQL query returning all rows (no loops necessary)? Do you mean "infinite" loop (ongoing as input table grows or just "for the whole table"? We don't know what you mean by "like", _explain_ what you mean by it, be clearer about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have this loop:

```
k.moveToFirst();
        //iterate over rows
        for (int i = 0; i < k.getCount(); i++) {

           nazwa = k.getString(0);
        szmax= k.getDouble(1);
           szmin= k.getDouble(2);
           dlmin= k.getDouble(3);
        dlmax= k.getDouble(4);
        opis = k.getString(5);
         a=szmax;
            b=szmin;
            c=dlmin;
            d=dlmax;

            wypisz +=i+nazwa+"-"+a+"-"+opis+"\n";
            tvBaza.setText(wypisz);

            k.moveToNext();

            }
```

the loop execute 5 times because I have 5 rows in database. I want to change it to execute over and over again.

Comment: hard to understand ( but not your English ) you have an event. based on this you read all records of a DB. either you find what you are looking for or not. the condition will not change if you read the DB a second or a third time. so why do you want to "execute" over and over ?

Comment: because I read data from GPS and my location is changing so variables are changing too.
<code>
double szerokosc = location.getLatitude();
    double dlugosc = location.getLongitude();
</code>
I want read first row compare it with gps data go to next row compare too ect. When i get last row I want to start from begin.

Comment: if your location changed than onLocationChanged() will be called too, isn't it ? no reason to run this again and again. your if-condition to check the coordinates is outside the while-loop. sounds strange. and the if-condition with k.moveToNext() is strange too. lokos for me, that you are checking only each second record of the DB.

Comment: You don't seem to be letting the database work for you. Make a query that asks for the exact information you want. Do you understand how to query with `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Could You give me a clue. I don't know how to explain this. 
My database have 5 rows. They looks like that:

---

1  Zone_A(nazwa), 50.03233693(dlmax), 50.0281259(dlmin), 22.00383871(szmin),   22.0094177(szmax), You are in zone_A(opis).

---

As You see I have coordinates and names in them.
My goal is to achieve somethin like that.

When my location change I get in to database check each row, if coordinates from one of them mach to the statement

```
    if(((szerokosc<=a)&&(szerokosc>=b)) && ((dlugosc>=c)&& (dlugosc<=d)))`
```

where

```
    a=szmax;b=szmin;c=dlmin;d=dlmax;
```

and

```
    double szerokosc = location.getLatitude();
    double dlugosc = location.getLongitude();
```

if they match display (nazwa+opis) if not dispaly(brak danych). 
When I am moving then data in

```
    double szerokosc = location.getLatitude();
    double dlugosc = location.getLongitude();
```

are changing too.

So I have to get in to database againg to check if one of row fits to new coordinates obtained from GPS which are saved in

```
    double szerokosc = location.getLatitude();
    double dlugosc = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: This is much better! Please list all your inputs and outputs: database plus variables. Also all your outputs. Don't talk about what you want to do; talk about what values you want, although it is ok to say "I want the value of x to be what it would be after I did ...". (Click on the "edit" link of your question and edit your "answers" into it one question.)